# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, nested-radicals

This question is spurred by my discussion here: [Find the value of : $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}-\sqrt{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629106/find-the-value-of-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrt/629145#comment4448666_629145)

My question is how do you prove what @Ant is claiming? It looks like a very useful simplification  when the number of nested radical signs grow big. So I'm looking for a proof of:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt{n}}$$

or at least a proof that one of the expressions can be substituted for the other in limit calculations.

Comment: Both $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ tend to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Requiring that one expression "can be substituted for the other" is a much stronger (not weaker) condition than both expressions having equal limits.

Comment: Maybe you can view this as an application of the squeeze theorem if you have heard of it.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good at calculus. You have to try and understand what I really mean.

Comment: *kingW3*'s answer is the correct one to your question (namely what you need for the reasoning in the linked post). Note that what you need is **not** "can always be substituted" which is **never true**, but rather "have ratio approaching $1$", which is in this case true.

Comment: Perhaps this might help $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581135/find-lim-x-to-infty-frac-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx/2632764#2632764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}=1$$ This follows by putting everything into one square root. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{n+\sqrt{n}}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=1$$
Another way to show that is to show $$\sqrt{n}\leq\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}\leq\sqrt{n}+\frac12$$

Answer (score 4):

Are you happy that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n = \infty?$$

If so you just need to note that

$$\sqrt n \le \sqrt{n + \sqrt n}$$

and then take the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Note however that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}- \sqrt{n}\right)\ne 0$$

Multiply and divide by the rational conjugate:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}- \sqrt{n}\right) & = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}- \sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+ \sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+ \sqrt{n}} \\
 & = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\cancel{n}+\sqrt{n} - \cancel{n}}{\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}+ \sqrt{n}} \\
 & = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}+ 1} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
$$