# Find: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}.$

Tags: limits, contest-math, radicals, nested-radicals

> Find: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}.$

Question from a book on preparation for math contests. All the tricks I know to solve this limit are not working. Wolfram Alpha struggled to find $1$ as the solution, but the solution process presented is not understandable. The answer is $1$.

Hints and solutions are appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried to divide both nominator and denominator by $\sqrt x$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A fun overkill: it is well known (at least among Ramanujan supporters) that for any $x>1$ we have
$$ \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\ldots}}}} = \tfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{x+\tfrac{1}{4}} $$
hence $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}$ is bounded between $1$ and $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}}$, whose limit as $x\to +\infty$ is also $1$.
The claim hence follows by squeezing.

Comment: Nice to see Ramanujan's name here. I am one of his supporters :) +1

Answer (score 12):

Note that
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^3}}}}}$$

You can also look at it as 
$$\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}$$ In case dividing by $\sqrt{x}$ bothers you.

Answer (score 10):

Divide by $\sqrt{x}$ to get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{\frac 1x + \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^3}}}}} = 1$$

Answer (score 5):

If you factor out a $\sqrt{x}$ term from the denominator one has
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}}} &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x} \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x} \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}}}}\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

$$\text{Let}\quad x=\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon\:\sqrt{1+\epsilon}}\qquad\qquad \epsilon\neq 0$$

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{1+\epsilon\:\sqrt{1+\epsilon}} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{1+\epsilon\sqrt{1}} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{1+\epsilon} =1$$

Comment: Why not directly $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{1+\epsilon\,\sqrt{1+\epsilon}} =1$? There are two redundant steps.

Comment: Just a teaching care. For you it is obvious that $\epsilon\sqrt{1+\epsilon}\to 0$. But this in not so obvious for some students who need more intermediate steps.

Comment: There is *no* intermediate step here! This limit can and should be computed by direct substitution. Would you do $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x-0}{x^3}$? I hope not, but your steps could give this idea to the students

Comment: @egreg Then the students need to have more redundant steps to understand the concept of limits :)

Comment: @user477343 The problem is that in general one *cannot* substitute only parts of an expression with its limit. In my opinion, these particular intermediate steps cal lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: @egreg I agree with you there. These types of steps can lead to misunderstanding of how limits truly work. But, unless some students were quite familiar with limits, then I’m sure there would not be a misunderstanding. The user, *JJacquelin*, brought forward the constant $\epsilon$ and so students with a rough understanding of limits would learn about this and not get a misunderstanding in the “redundant” steps. However, students who are just starting to learn, these steps might lead to a misunderstanding for them, considering how they wouldn’t know why $\epsilon$ is there in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=√x$. $\lim x \rightarrow \infty =\lim y \rightarrow \infty. $

Numerator: $y$

Denominator:

$\sqrt {y^2 +\sqrt{y^2+y}}= \sqrt{y^2+y\sqrt{1+1/y}}=$

$y\sqrt{1+(1/y)\sqrt{1+1/y}}.$

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{y}{y \sqrt{1+(1/y) \sqrt{1+1/y}}}= $

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+(1/y)\sqrt{1+1/y}}} =1.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Lambda =$ the limit we need to find. Then, $ \ \Box\ \Lambda = 1$.

---

*Proof*: We will begin our proof using the following *Lemma*. $$\forall a, b\in\mathbb{R}, \ \sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - b}}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - b}}{2}}.\tag1$$
Substitute $a = x$ and $b = x + \sqrt{x}$ into the Lemma. $$(1) = \sqrt{\frac{x + \sqrt{x^2 - x + \sqrt{x}}}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{x - \sqrt{x^2 - x + \sqrt{x}}}{2}}.$$ Find the limit of the fractions under each root.$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - x + \sqrt{x}}}{2} = \frac 12\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg(x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - x + \sqrt{x}}\bigg) = \frac12\cdot\infty = \infty$$ $$\therefore \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}}} = \sqrt{\infty} + \sqrt{\infty} = \infty + \infty = \infty.$$ And, $\because \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x} = \infty$ then we finally have as desired. $$\Lambda = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x +\sqrt{x}}}} = \frac{\infty}{\infty} = 1$$ $$\therefore \Lambda = 1.\tag*{$\bigcirc$}$$

Comment: @downvoter care to explain why I was downvoted? Is there a way I could improve my answer? :)